# How to programmatically copy Webform handler config?

Tags: 8, webforms

I would like to copy the Webform handler from 1 Webform into another. I can get hold of Webform settings via:

```
/** @var \Drupal\webform\WebformInterface $webform */
$webform = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('webform')->load('example_webform_id');
$webform->getSettings();
=> [
     "ajax" => false,
     "ajax_scroll_top" => "",
     "ajax_progress_type" => "",
     "ajax_effect" => "",
     ...
```

However that doesn't include the handler config that I would need and a way to save its new config as well.

I also tried it via the handler object itself:

```
/** @var \Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandlerInterface[] $handlers */
$handlers = $webform->getHandlers('example_webform_handler_id');
$handler = $handlers->getIterator()->current();
$handler->setConfiguration($new_handler_config)->save();
```

for which it appears that there is no `save()` operation in the handler class:

> Error: Call to undefined method ::save()

Any way I can do this programmatically that you may know of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up using the `ConfigFactory` service, which I believe is fine to do:

```
$config = \Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable('webform.webform.' . $webform->id());
$config_key = 'handlers.' . $webform_handler_id;
$config->set($config_key, $new_handler_config)->save();
```